# Bootstrap 4: Scrollspy isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Im am working on this site right now: https://handyfreak011.github.io/FreetimeElements/. 
I already set

```
body { position: relative;}
```

And applied

```
<body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" data-offset="150">
```

To my body.

That is my nav:

```html
    <nav class="navbar main-nav" id="main-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navibar" aria-controls="navibar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      &#9776;
                  </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navibar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#info">START</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#philo">PHILOSOPHIE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#products">PRODUKTE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">KONTAKT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The ID's of the elements are as in the navigation and if you klick them in the nav, you are sent there. But scrollspy isn't working, the navbar's elements don't change to active when you scroll in the area.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Works for me, little jumpy though... might need to adjust the offset.

Comment: So it's changing the nav's active classes ? Because they don't change if I am scrolling...

Comment: Yes, the nav changes to `navbar main-nav main-nav-scrolled` when you scroll past the offset position.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that the scrollSpy isn't working. It should show the active element in the nav bar at the top!

Comment: I think it is working, you just do not have the styles to differentiate the active element. For example, try adding these styles and see the examples  `a.nav-link.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}`